# Getting Index was outside the bounds of the array when converting hex string to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, hex, byte

I have a hex string that I convert over to array of bytes. I am not sure if it's because of the length of the string? 
Example of a string that work:

```
"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\n\n"
```

a string that throws and error
`Index was outside the bounds of the array`:

```
"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\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\n\n"
```

This the method that converts:

```
private byte[] hexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
    {
        int len = (hexString.Length - 2);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
        {
            byte b = byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            byteArray[i / 2] = b;
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
```

I found another way but this throws a different exception of: `System.FormatException: Could not find any recognizable digits`.`

```
private byte[] hexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
    int NumberChars = hexString.Length - 2;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 2; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Hint: look at the characters at the end of that string. They don't look like hex digits to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion method is working fine.

The problem is with the provided string. It has 3 **linebreaks** 2 at the end and 1 in the middle.

You can either strip the line breaks from the **hexString** with

```
hexString = hexString.Replace("\n","");
```

or just use this string. I stripped the linebreaks for you.

> "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"